# Google Service Account Setting up Auto Forwarding getting 401

Tags: dns, delegation

As a service account am trying to set up auto forwarding for others users.But am getting 401 Unauthorized.Below is my code.Please let me know what I am doing wrong.All these scopes and more are added to the Domain Wide delegation

```
           

    Gmail service = null;
                        GoogleCredentials credentials;
                        try {
                            credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON2_FILE_PATH))
                                .createScoped(SCOPES)
                                .createDelegated(userEmail);
    
                            HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);
    
                            // Create the gmail API client
                            service = new Gmail.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                                    GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                                    requestInitializer)
                                .setApplicationName("Gmail samples")
                                .build();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
    
                        public static void enableAutoForward(String userEmail, String forwardingEmail, Gmail service) throws Exception {
    
                            try {
                                // Enable auto-forwarding and move forwarded messages to the trash
                                ForwardingAddress address = new ForwardingAddress().setForwardingEmail(forwardingEmail);
                                ForwardingAddress createAddressResult = service.users()
                                    .settings()
                                    .forwardingAddresses()
                                    .create("me", address)
                                    .execute();
                                if (createAddressResult.getVerificationStatus().equals("accepted")) {
                                    AutoForwarding autoForwarding = new AutoForwarding().setEnabled(true)
                                        .setEmailAddress(address.getForwardingEmail())
                                        .setDisposition("trash");
                                    autoForwarding = service.users()
                                        .settings()
                                        .updateAutoForwarding("me", autoForwarding)
                                        .execute();
                                    System.out.println(autoForwarding.toPrettyString());
    
                                }
                            } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
                                // TODO(developer) - handle error appropriately
                                System.err.println("Unable to enable forwarding : " + e.getDetails());
                                throw e;
                            }
    
                        }
    
                        public static void main(String[] args) {
                            GoogleEnableForwarding googlenabledFwd = new GoogleEnableForwarding();
                            String userEmail = "XXXXX";
                            try {
                                Gmail gmailService = GoogleEnableForwarding.getService(userEmail);
                                GoogleEnableForwarding.enableAutoForward(userEmail, "adminEmail", gmailService);
    
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
    
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it.I had added too many scopes .When I reduced it to the bare minimum it worked